# How to use the container name in rancher inside the application code running within the container

Tags: node.js, docker, rancher, appdynamics

Having a nodejs application running inside a docker container orchestrated by Rancher. Using appdynamics to monitor the service. For that we need to add few configuration parameters in main js file. One of the configuration has to be unique for all the containers running for this service. So, i would like to pass the rancher container name as that configuration.

Comment: Are you using Rancher 1.6 or 2.0? If it is 1.6, what orchestration option are you using? Cattle or Kubernetes?

Comment: My version is v1.6.20 and orchestration option is Cattle

Comment: Did you try querying the rancher-metadata? `curl http://rancher-metadata/latest/self`? I don't have a setup handy, but you can find the container name which can be used in your config.

Comment: Just wondering where to add this curl command. In rancher.compose.yml or as bash script in my application eg: ENV NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER=`curl -s rancher-metadata/latest/self/container/name`?

Comment: You need to add it inside your app as bash script. That's the startup script for the container, it fetches the info and then starts your app binary.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: yes. thanks for the answer. It solved my problem @leodotcloud